# jQuery replace all URLs with specific location

Tags: jquery

I want to replace all URLs in side my page:

**`http://domain.com/media/image/`**

with

**`//cdn.url.com`**

How can I fetch all URLs to replace with ?

I tried

```
$( "http://domain.com/media/image/" ).replaceAll( "//cdn.com" );
```

But this does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this using **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** and **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)**

```js
$('body').html(function(i, v) {
  return v.replace('http://domain.com/media/image/', '//cdn.url.com','g');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
http://domain.com/media/image/


http://domain.com/media/image/


http://domain.com/media/image/

http://domain.com/media/image/
```